# The word 'array' is being printed within my numpy 2d array of floats and strings

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I'm trying to make a 2d array of floats with some strings. I've broken it down to make 2 arrays separately and then try to combine them into a 2d array but the literal word 'array' is printing. The problem is not replicated when I use the smaller arrays listed at the bottom.

If I do it like np.array([...][...]) then I get [list(...), list(...)]

**My code**

```
a = np.array([75.145, 70.082, '-', 65.537, 76.230, 68.224, 69.841, 75.962, 72.963, 84.492, 73.016, 78.571, 75.314, 76.812, 68.504, 73.004])
b = np.array(['-', 70.124, 67.873, 67.630, 76.230, 81.250, 66.990, 66.559, 66.860, 80.749, 69.780, 77.249, 84.058, 79.592, 78.261, 72.174, 73.507])
c = [a, b]
d = np.array(c)
print(d)
```

**Output**

```
[array(['75.145', '70.082', '-', '65.537', '76.23', '68.224', '69.841',
       '75.962', '72.963', '84.492', '73.016', '78.571', '75.314',
       '76.812', '68.504', '73.004'], dtype='<U32')
 array(['-', '70.124', '67.873', '67.63', '76.23', '81.25', '66.99',
       '66.559', '66.86', '80.749', '69.78', '77.249', '84.058', '79.592',
       '78.261', '72.174', '73.507'], dtype='<U6')] #Somehow there's not even a closing ] here
```

**Desired Output**

```
[['75.145' '70.082' '-' '65.537' '76.23' '68.224' '69.841' '75.962', '72.963' '84.492' '73.016' '78.571' '75.314' '76.812' '68.504' '73.004'],
```

['-', '70.124', '67.873', '67.63', '76.23', '81.25', '66.99', '66.559', '66.86', '80.749', '69.78', '77.249', '84.058', '79.592', '78.261', '72.174', '73.507']]

**Smaller arrays where problem is not replicated.**

```
a = np.array([75.145, 70.082, '-'])
b = np.array(['-', 70.124, 67.873])
c = [a, b]
d = np.array(c)
print(d)

[['75.145' '70.082' '-']
 ['-' '70.124' '67.873']]
```

Comment: NumPy arrays aren't designed for mixed data types or inconsistent lengths. Why are you trying to put hyphens in your array, anyway?

Comment: `a` and `b` have different lengths (16 and 17), and `c` is (2,) shape array with object dtype.  It's an array containing 2 arrays, not a 2d array like your small example.

Comment: @hpaulj Thank you. I wouldn't have thought of that. It worked

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([1,2,3,4,'-',4])
a.tolist()
```